# how provider sends notification to APNs?

Tags: iphone, push-notification, provider

i want to know that if i have a server how do i send push notification to devices through APNs,do i need to register/authenticate my server to APNs.DO i need to pay for sending Push Notification?Any sample code related to this will help better to understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through following doc. It explains in depth the entire system.

[Apple's Good Doc About APN](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW1)
Feel free to vote the answer, if you find it helpful.

Comment: i read that guide but unable to understand.can you explain this in an easy way

Comment: I think Apple doc is good guide.Let me know what you want to achieve? So will try to help you.